# Django cookicecutter Docker not working [build errors]

Tags: django, docker, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I have been getting the below terminal errors when running:

`docker-compose -f local.yml build`

While following the docs here for running cookiecutter-django locally:

[cookiecutter django docs](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/2022.03.27/developing-locally-docker.html)

The output I am getting where it freezes is shown below:

```
 => ERROR [docs python-build-stage 3/3] RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wh  9.0s
 => [django internal] load .dockerignore                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 211B                                                                 0.0s
 => [django internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.73kB                                                            0.0s
 => [celerybeat internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.73kB                                                            0.0s
 => [celerybeat internal] load .dockerignore                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 211B                                                                 0.0s
 => [celerybeat internal] load build context                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 14.61kB                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [celeryworker python-run-stage  1/22] WORKDIR /app                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [celeryworker python-run-stage  2/22] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-inst  0.0s
 => CACHED [celeryworker python-run-stage  3/22] RUN groupadd --gid 1000 dev-user   && useradd -  0.0s
 => CACHED [celeryworker python-run-stage  4/22] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-inst  0.0s
 => [django internal] load build context                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 14.61kB                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [celerybeat python-build-stage 1/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-instal  0.0s
 => CACHED [celerybeat python-build-stage 2/3] COPY ./requirements .                              0.0s
 => CANCELED [celerybeat python-build-stage 3/3] RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels    8.5s
 => [celeryworker internal] load .dockerignore                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 211B                                                                 0.0s
 => [celeryworker internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.73kB                                                            0.0s
 => [flower internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.73kB                                                            0.0s
 => [flower internal] load .dockerignore                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 211B                                                                 0.0s
 => [flower internal] load build context                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 14.61kB                                                              0.0s
 => [celeryworker internal] load build context                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 14.61kB
```

Once it reaches the above state it freezes.

I have tried deleting the images via:

`docker system prune -a`

Rerunning but essentially the same result, after checking also I have the correct prerequisites installed in my system.

Any help with this would be great!

I have tried deleting the images via:

`docker system prune -a`

Rerunning but essentially the same result, after checking also I have the correct prerequisites installed in my system.

Here is the contents of my local.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  report_writer_local_postgres_data: {}
  report_writer_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: report_writer_local_django
    container_name: report_writer_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: report_writer_production_postgres
    container_name: report_writer_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - report_writer_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - report_writer_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: report_writer_local_docs
    container_name: report_writer_local_docs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./report_writer:/app/report_writer:z
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    command: /start-docs

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    container_name: report_writer_local_mailhog
    ports:
      - '8025:8025'

  redis:
    image: redis:6
    container_name: report_writer_local_redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: report_writer_local_celeryworker
    container_name: report_writer_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: report_writer_local_celerybeat
    container_name: report_writer_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: report_writer_local_flower
    container_name: report_writer_local_flower
    ports:
      - '5555:5555'
    command: /start-flower

  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/node/Dockerfile
    image: report_writer_local_node
    container_name: report_writer_local_node
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
      # http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

And here is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
# define an alias for the specific python version used in this file.
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye as python

# Python build stage
FROM python as python-build-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local

# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements .

# Create Python Dependency and Sub-Dependency Wheels.
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels  \
  -r ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}.txt


# Python 'run' stage
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local
ARG APP_HOME=/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV BUILD_ENV ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}


# devcontainer dependencies and utils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  sudo git bash-completion nano ssh

# Create devcontainer user and add it to sudoers
RUN groupadd --gid 1000 dev-user \
  && useradd --uid 1000 --gid dev-user --shell /bin/bash --create-home dev-user \
  && echo dev-user ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/dev-user \
  && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/dev-user


# Install required system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  gettext \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# All absolute dir copies ignore workdir instruction. All relative dir copies are wrt to the workdir instruction
# copy python dependency wheels from python-build-stage
COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels  /wheels/

# use wheels to install python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/wheels/ /wheels/* \
  && rm -rf /wheels/

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start


COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower


# copy application code to WORKDIR
COPY . ${APP_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially your Compose `local.yml` file (consider renaming this to the standard `docker-compose.yml`) and your image's Dockerfile?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Please replace the PNG-format output with the raw text of the build output as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the reminder, I have included the contents of my local.yml file and Dockerfile